# "Silencium" hat trigger details?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

The trigger for the Silencium hat says

> answer a question that has never been commented on; your answer gets no comments and scores 7+

Which makes it sound like the question can get comments on it after I post an answer. However the short description says

> answer +7 with no comments on Q or A

Which seems to imply that neither the answer nor the question can have any comments.

So does the answer have to reach +7 with no comments on both my answer and the question? What about other answers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Winter Bash 2017 Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats)

Comment: @Mureinik a dup, seriously? I made the hat post. I quote the hat trigger. This is asking for "details" on the trigger.

Answer (score 5):

With the help of [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/773875/possible-silencium-candidates-with-comments-on-the-q-after-posting-the-a) I think I can probably give a definitive answer to this.

For example, [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47796243/4751173)

- has a score of 7
- was posted (a couple of seconds) before the first comment on the question
- has no comments

but [its owner does not have the Silencium hat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5245033/sergeya?tab=topactivity#winter-bash). So that means the short description is correct.

---

Note that the hat is identical to the "007" hat from the 2015 edition. I found [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26155813#26155813) by Logan M:

> I'm now almost positive the requirement is 7 score with no comments on the question or answer, possibly <30 minutes required as well.

and the description in [Winter Bash 2015 Secret Hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270789/295232) does not imply that the question can receive comments after you post your answer (and before you get the hat).

---

> What about other answers?

I can answer this part from personal experience; I got my Silencium hat for [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304410/295232) while there were comments on Journeyman Geek's answer (long before my answer reached +7). So the other answers aren't checked for comments.